# Older Satellite Images from Saudi Arabia

Tags: data-request, geospatial, asia

For Research purposes on "how Sprawl effects Urbans", Is it possible to get a 50 OR 40 years old Image of a certain location ( 26°37'59.59"N,  49°58'3.32"E) in the eastern province of Saudi Arabia. Google Earth Pro gave me 15 years back only.

Comment: te are Landsat images back to 1976, but there was no systematic acquistion at the time so you you have to be lucky.

Comment: Could also go for the good old Corona / Keyhole spy images from the declassified American datasets. Could have a coverage with around 1m resolution in black and white from the 60s or 70s.

Answer (score 3):

You can search the Earth Explorer website by the USGS. It is a fairly complete archive of what is available from most western agencies.

You can search by date and location.
https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/

Check the classified data and the Landsat archive. It has data for your location from 1960s (Corona), 1973 (Landsat) and 1980s (Corona). That's what I found with a quick search, there may be more.